# Listbox align text

Tags: c#, listbox, alignment

I have a `ListBox` containing 2 elements: `item and price`.

I add them like so:

```
lbtest.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem()
{
    Content = item + prijs,
    FontSize = 14,
    Foreground = Brushes.Red
});
```

Now of course this results into:

```
--------------------
Fries€2,00 // btw they are from Belgium NOT from France lol
    Ketchup€0,30
Burger€2,00
    Onion€0,10
SomeFood€2,00
    SomeSubItem€500
--------------------
```

I played around with `.PadLeft` and `.PadRight` but these aren't giving me the conditions i want:

```
--------------------
Fries              €2,00
    Ketchup        €0,30
Burger             €2,00
    Onion          €0,10
SomeFood           €2,00
    SomeSubItem    €500
--------------------
```

Is there some kind of calculation i can use to achieve this ?

My `ListBox` has a static width, maybe i can do something with that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try working with:

```
    var name = "ItemName";
    var price = "€2,00";

    var daa = String.Format("{0, 5} {1, 10}", name, price);
```

That results in:

```
"ItemName      €2,00"
```

The **{0,1,2.., [align]}** is quite nice